# mod_rewrite rule to match first letter

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have urls structured like this http://domain.com/search.php?query=perks
I want to be able to match the first letter of the query "in this case perks" and make a url like this
http://domain.com/p/perks
I would also like it so that if the query starts with a number EX query "1 perk" that it will make a url like this.
domain.com/1/1+perk
Does anyone know how to achieve the matching of the first character of the search to make urls structured like this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) explains,

> If you wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use a `RewriteCond` with the `%{HTTP_HOST}`, `%{SERVER_PORT}`, or `%{QUERY_STRING}` variables respectively.

Therefore, the solution is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)query=(([^&])[^&]*)
RewriteRule ^/search.php /%3/%2?
```

By the way, the `+` decodes to a space character only if it is in a query string.  A space in the path portion of a URL should be encoded as `%20`; a `+` in the path portion of the URL should generally be interpreted literally.